# VBA - hlookup - method of range error

Tags: vba

I am trying to use an hLookup in VBA referencing another sheet in the same workbook. I am referencing all of the cells by sheet explicitly but am still getting an error with the hLookup.

```
Sub updateSettles()

Dim settles As Worksheet
Dim swaps As Worksheet
Dim flys As Worksheet
Dim lookupRange As Range



Set settles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settles")
Set swaps = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Swaps")
Set flys = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flys")

tradeDate = flys.Range("y2").Value

'update settles
lastcol = settles.Range("b3").End(xlToRight).Column
lastcol2 = swaps.Range("b1").End(xlToRight).Column
Set lookupRange = swaps.Range(swaps.Cells(2, 2), swaps.Cells(13, lastcol2))

For i = 2 To lastcol
settles.Range(4, i).Value =   Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(settles.Range(settles.Cells(2, i)),   swaps.Range(swaps.Cells(2, 2), swaps.Cells(13, lastcol2)), 12, False)
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Range(4, i).Value` ? You mean ` Cells(4, i).Value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HLookup(settles.Range(settles.Cells(2, i)),   swaps.Range(swaps.Cells(2, 2), swaps.Cells(13, lastcol2)), 12, False)

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the `Range` method needs either a String address or **two** cells as parameters. It doesnt work with only one cell as parameter. What you surely meant is:

```
HLookup(settles.Cells(2, i).Value, swaps.Range(swaps.Cells(2, 2), swaps.Cells(13, lastcol2)), 12, False)
```

Comment: Wow I didn't realize that. Thank you! I knew it had to be something dumb.